# How can I place this child div using position:absolute inside the parent div?

Tags: css

I have a div in which I am trying to place div in the form of a box. The problem is I need to use `position:absolute` to maintain the flexibilty. But when I apply `position: absolute` the box goes out of the parent div.

Image with

```
    .new-div{
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);


    /*float: left;*/
    min-width: 3em;
    min-height: 2em;
    max-width: 48ex;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 70%;
    position: absolute;

    word-wrap:break-word;
    top: 52%;

    /*left: 50%;*/
    /*right: -2%;*/
    /*transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);*/
    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

[image]

The moment I remove `position: absolute` it works fine.
[image]

But I need to use `position:absolute`. Can somebody please suggest a workaround.

Comment: give the parent a relative position

Comment: I already tried using that <div class="aui-page-panel-nav"  style="position: relative"> but that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Parent div position should be relative.

```
<div style='position:relative'>
    <div class='new-div'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the problem I already have tried the position:relative for parent div but that is not working. I am using https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/page-content-layout.html

Comment: .aui-page-panel-nav has display:table-cell attribute. Just add display:table-cell in new-id class and delete position:absolute.